# Can you change the stock quote provider (yahoo) in OSX (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, notifications, osx-yosemite, yahoo, stocks

I'd like to use the Notifications center to display some Canadian stocks. Yahoo does not support these listings, but other providers like Google do.

Is there a way to change/hack OSXs default provider of stock quote information to something other then Yahoo?